Wrong alignment of timestamp for short messages in moderator dropdown
In the moderator messages dropdown, when both the title/summary and the body are short, the relative timestamp is not right-aligned, but immediately follows the preceding element without any padding:

This fortunately does not happen in the global inbox:

